# How does scammer get money by spamming their 'Ethereum password' in comments?

Tags: scams

I've noticed on a certain website the same message keeps being spammed as a random reply to comments.  The message is:

> Hi. How can i withdraw tokens? ethereum pass 0x(long hex ID here)

I'm sure they wouldn't bother to spam people if they didn't anticipate getting money out of it somehow, but I honestly can't imagine how the scam would set someone up to scam money.

Anyone able to explain how this scam is suppose to work?

Comment: Technical questions on cryptocurrency aren’t a good fit for this site. You will probably get a better response asking your question at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I don't think this is a technical question about cryptocurrancy.  The password is just a code that would let someone open their wallet, basically it gives them access to their money same as a password to a bank account lets someone transfer money from it.  What I'm asking is how can posting a presumably fake password help a scammer to get something out of someone that falls for it?  The question is about the scam, the fact that this scam used etherium instead of a bank account number doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Is that address their public address? https://info.etherscan.com/what-is-an-ethereum-address/ Calling it a "pass" or "password" could be jargon or simply the wrong term.